# Rails Arel, Select from same column but multiple values

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

I have a table called `cherry_picker_cherries`. These records polymorphically belong to a model called `Pickable`. They can have multiple entries in the table for the same pickable, but it always has a different `cherry_pick_id`.

**My problem:** I have a cherry pick called `Favorite Tree` and a separate cherry_pick called `Favorite Fruit`. I want to be able to filter a collection of pickables by multiple cherry picks. For example, I want to find all pickables that have a favorite tree of `cherry` AND have a Favorite Fruit of `orange`.

I can accomplish this in a terrible manner using the following:

`CherryPicker::Cherry.find_by_sql("SELECT * from cherry_picker_cherries t1 JOIN cherry_picker_cherries t2 USING(pickable_id) WHERE t1.value = 'orange'AND t2.value = 'cherry'")`

However, there are **several** drawbacks to this approach. It doesn't handle even more Cherry Picks, only two right now. Also, the resultant set is converted into an array, but I need to return an ActiveRecord relation so that I can continue to chain methods onto it.

I was trying to see if AREL had some kind of solution to generate a simple query that would match the above, but I am stuck at a dead end. It would be easy enough to loop over the hash of parameters to allow for 2,3, 4 or X number of cherry picks that you could filter by.

Is this even possible in AREL, rails, or anything else?

Comment: Let me know if my code below works for you so I can edit it to be more general =)

Answer (score 0):

Can you give this a shot?

`CherryPicker::Cherry.joins("join cherry_picker_cherries t2 using(pickable_id)").where("cherry_picker_cherries.value = ? and t2.value = ?", 'orange', 'cherry')`

If this works, you can iterate over the fruits you want to join and do another `joins` with an incremented variable name (t3, t4.. etc) because the sql query will not be executed until it's needed.

Here's how to join the same table on itself multiple times:

```
arr = ['orange', 'cherry', 'apple']

query = CherryPicker::Cherry.joins("join cherry_picker_cherries t0 using(pickable_id)")

arr.drop(2).each_with_index do |e,i|
  query = query.joins("join cherry_picker_cherries t#{i+1} using(pickable_id)")
end
```

You can do the same to generate your `where`s

It would be great if you could suggest edits so I can improve this post as it's really hard to test without having your tables =)

Comment: Cool.. Now can you give me an example with multiple cherry picks?

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is actually part of the larger problem, but I did manage to make it work using the bits and pieces you gave me:

```
def self.with_cherries(params={})
  # See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689795/rails-arel-select-from-same-column-but-multiple-values
  result = all
  if (params.keys.length > 1)
    # filtering by 2 or more cherry picks
    result = result.joins(:cherries).where("cherry_picker_cherries.pickable_type = ?", self.name)

    # Setup the complicated joins
    params.each_with_index do |cherry_pick_and_value, index|
      result = result.joins("JOIN cherry_picker_cherries t#{index} USING(pickable_id)") unless index.zero?
    end

    my_query_string = ""
    params.values.each_with_index do |k, i|
      if i.zero?
        my_query_string << "cherry_picker_cherries.value = ?"
      else
        my_query_string << " AND t#{i}.value = ?"
      end
    end
    sanitized_string = self.sanitize_sql_array([my_query_string, params.values].flatten)
    result = result.where(sanitized_string).references(:cherries)
  else
    if params.present? && (params.keys.length == 1)
      # Only filtering by a single cherry pick
      result = result.with_cherry(params.first.first, params.first.last)
    end
  end
  result
end
```